# What is the best definition of an RTOS?

Tags: rtos

I have yet to find a definition of an RTOS that is specific enough to have meaning.  The best one I can find is on wiki:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system

However I have some critical comments/questions:

1. "Real Time" seems to be undefined in all the definitions for RTOS I've found.  Nothing can be fast as actual real time (infinitesimally small!).  Therefore, I believe "real time" only makes sense in the context of the observer.  Real time for a human using an iPhone user might be <20ms because human eye sight cannot detect changes faster than that.  For an air bag deployment it might be <1ms.  All definitions on the internet seem to gloss over the definition of "real time"!

If RTOS is defined by the requirement to execute something within a specific time frame ("deadline"), why does jitter come into the definition?  If the iPhone response jitters between 12-14ms, is it no longer responding in real time?  It meets the 20ms requirement, right?  If one time the response went to 100ms, the user might notice, at which point the system is not an RTOS

How can there possibly be a "soft" RTOS?!  The definition of RTOS is meeting a particular deadline time requirement.  If it doesn't meet it, than its not an RTOS!  The very definition of RTOS prohibits a "soft" RTOS

To me it seems there is no formal and precise definition of RTOS.  It's a general term to explain the characteristic of an OS who's main priority is the appearance of "real time" (per requirement number) to a particular type of observer.  It also seems like the name has taken on implementation meaning such as how things are processed, multi-tasking, message passing, semaphores, etc... all which may NOT be part of an RTOS at all if the system fails to respond within the "deadline" requirement, right?

Sorry about such a ubiquitous question, but I can't get a clear picture in my brain.  All definitions I've found are simply not precise enough or cloud the definition with implementation details.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no standard body which defines an exact meaning of RTOS, and therefore the term is poorly defined, just like terms such as "PC" or "Automobile". Any answer beyond that will have to be primarily opinion based.

Comment: Whilst yes,  this is a brilliant question and I'd be interested in reading the answers provided.. Unfortunately,  a question like this is not suitable for stackoverflow as it has no programming issue, only theoretical scenarios with non optimised code/server performance. A question like this is best suited for superuser.com

Comment: @DarylGill: "non-optimized code" is in fact rather common for real-time code. That's because you very much prefer guaranteed performance over average performance. 10-12 milliseconds is better than 1-13 milliseconds, in real-time code, even though 11 > 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [Embedded Systems Dictionary](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1578201209).  Here are some excerpts:

> **real-time** adj. Having timeliness requirements, typically in the form of deadlines that can’t be missed.
>
> **real-time operating system** n. An operating system designed specifically for use in real-time systems. Abbreviated RTOS.
>
> **real-time system** n. Any computer system, embedded or otherwise, that has timeliness requirements. The following question can be used
>   to distinguish real-time systems from the rest: “Is a late answer as
>   bad, or even worse, than a wrong answer?” In other words, what happens
>   if the computation doesn’t finish in time? If nothing bad happens,
>   it’s not a real-time system. If someone dies or the mission fails,
>   it’s generally considered “hard” real-time, which is meant to imply
>   that the system has hard deadlines. Everything in between is “soft”
>   real-time.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that no definition defines the exact time bounds. That's not the goal of a definition. Real time isn't dependent on the observer, though, but the application. As applications differ, time bounds differ, and therefore  a definition cannot give that bound as a number.

Jitter is irrelevant as long as the application's time bound is met. You're absolutely right about the example. If the deadline is 20 ms, taking 100 ms is a failure. If the OS is to blame for the delay, it's not an RTOS.

"Soft realtime" has a very specific meaning, and this is probably the only thing you really got wrong. The concept at work here is, what do you do when a task exceeds its deadline? (Note: this could be either the fault of the task itself or the RTOS.) In a hard realtime system, the task simply has no value anymore. A late outcome is as good as no outcome, and you cancel the task. No point in risking other tasks.

Soft RTOS is actually more complex. Finishing the task still has value, although diminished. So the RTOS cannot hard kill the task, but the OS still has to ensure other tasks meet their deadlines. That requires extra care, which wouldn't have been necessary if you'd just kill the task.

Comment: Thanks, note that I'm not looking for a time bound in the definition of RTOS, rather I'm trying to establish the definition of "real time" in the context of RTOS.  I used the word "observer", but also thought about using "application" like you state.